# App icon is not displaying in Apple Watch App

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

[image]

I am developing my first iWatch App, i added icons for watch app in Image Assets folder of Application.But when i install app in iWatch, then App icon not displaying.
Please find image , which showing app without Icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the correct icons with the correct size not in the iOS App Xcassests but in the WatchApp Xcassetes.