# Apple Watch icon not displaying in the "Watch" app on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

My Apple Watch icon is not displaying in the "Watch" app on iPhone. 
I added all the required Apple Watch icons to `Assets.xcassets` in the parent target and in the Watch target, but the icon is still missing.

Where can I add the icon for the "Watch" app?

Answer (score 0):

According to [App icon is not displaying in Apple Watch App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993946/app-icon-is-not-displaying-in-apple-watch-app)

"You have to put the correct icons with the correct size not in the iOS App Xcassests but in the WatchApp Xcassetes." - Lorenzo

Comment: I put all the icons with the correct size in both xcassests. All icons is displaying correct. Only one from the "Watch" app is missing.

Comment: Did you follow https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/icons-and-images/home-screen-icons/#sizes ? Also, did you add the Icons for the watch in the Images.xcassets file in the WatchKit App folder?

Comment: I also see some people encountered issue and fixed by just resetting devices. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667961/ios-app-icon-is-not-showing-in-watch-companion-app

Comment: Now it's not displaying for one parent target and displaying for another. Probably should try to unpair watches or do smth like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33796917/10596896. 
Thank you!